# How access GWT servlets using some way other than GWT-RPC?

Tags: gwt, servlets, soap, rpc

Is it possible to access GWT servlets using some protocol other than GWT-RPC (such AS SOAP)?

If yes is it required to make any changes on them?

If no how can I make GWT-RPC request manually & parse & convert server response from GWT-RPC to any other format (i.e. is there any third-party library to do this)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access GWT servlets using protocols other than GWT-RPC by using an HttpRequest.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideHttpRequests

It's quite common to use JSON in this manner.  A tutorial is here https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/tutorial/JSON

Still, what format do you need?  You can pass back data as an object to the client.  If you are not making the request from a GWT client, then no you probably don't want to use rpc.

As for SOAP, have a look at the good discussion here  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/M2KshXZkLUo

### Summary

From a GWT client use RPC or a RequestBuilder (HttpRequest)

http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/http/client/package-summary.html

If you need to call from a non-gwt client, then just use a servlet and don't bother trying to convert a returned rpc call.

Comment: Caution though, if the SOAP server is not the same as the one your GWT app is deployed on, you may experience cross-domain security issues.

Comment: Yeah, but in that case wouldn't you do an rpc call to the server and then SOAP call from there, returning the results via rpc?

Comment: Indeed, that's what I do to access RESTful webservices that live on another server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464987/gwt-json-parsing-in-client-side-and-server-side-with-same-api/11516919#11516919